# Why was my "SO answering workflow" question closed? How could I rephrase it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, meta

**Question in question:** [What is your SO answering "workflow"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145687/what-is-your-so-answering-workflow)

Since this was closed, I guess I don't quite get what belongs/doesn't belong on meta. I'm asking so that I hopefully don't ask a bad question here again, and because I'm not sure how much the "closed as not constructive" comment applies in this case.

It was closed as not a good fit, but I guess I don't see why not. SO has a lot of little details; what better way for a new user to see how to approach the site than to have him/her see how established users do it?

Comment: It seems constructive to me, but, perhaps, instead of asking why, ask how it can be rephrased.

Comment: Well you are asking potentially _every_ SO user about their answering workflow, that rarely turns out well. We've seen similarly formulated questions get tons of answers years after they were posted, and at some point it becomes impossible to navigate them. "not constructive" means just that, that your question has little chance of building up to a useful Q&A thread, not that the tone of it was not constructive. Although if that was the case, it would still probably be closed as NC, as unfortunately MSO doesn't have the "noise and pointless" close reason anymore...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Posts on Meta have a lot of leeway; a lot of the things that normally wouldn't be allowed on the main site are allowed on Meta, as long (not always) as it's in the pursuit of advancing the site in some way.

However, your question didn't help to advance the site (the main site or meta) in any way, you simply asked what people's workflow is on the main site.

The question could *possibly* be constructive (I'll be honest, I'm giving it the benefit of the doubt, right now, I don't really see *how*), but as it stands right now, it's just an open call for people to describe how they interact with the site.  Even for meta, that's not a good fit for the site.  A gazillion people will answer and there's no way to come to a consensus about which approach is the best using the system in place.

Comment: (A response from one of the people who closed it- nice.) I think it advances the site by educating newer users. <stupid analogy>Watching someone build a table is a lot more effective than just handing them building a table FAQ.</stupid analogy> Also, maybe this is naive, but I would think that there wouldn't be too many answers b/c there are only so many ways to go about using the site that aren't very similar to each other.

Comment: @MatthewAdams I appreciate that you think it advances the site, but it doesn't really guide the user down any particular path.  And if they used votes and took the highest voted one and it didn't work, then that's a bad experience for them.  The more constructive thing for new users is to ask very specific questions about what they want to do when developing their workflow (ask about favorites, sorting of questions, tags of interest, etc.) and then have people answer those.  There's no good way of navigating through the list that you were trying to curate.